# Obtaining Velocity from Acceleration

Tags: kinematics, acceleration, velocity, computational-physics

I'm following [a research paper](http://dx.doi.org/10.1109/PLANS.2010.5507251) ([PDF via RG](http://www.researchgate.net/publication/224154935_Accelerometer_Assisted_Robust_Wireless_Signal_Positioning_Based_on_a_Hidden_Markov_Model)), part of which is about using the accelerometer of a smartphone to assist the user's positioning via WLAN.

Accelerometer is used to determine if the user is static, slow walking or fast walking.

Here is the algorithm:

[image: Pedestrian Status Determination via Accelerometer]

For the implementation I'm using Swift on iOS. I've calculated the Euclidian Norm of the accelerometer data which I receive every second.

The problem is that I'm having difficulty obtaining $v_a$ in the algorithm. How should I pass from acceleration to $v_a$ in this particular situation?

Comment: what is your specific difficulty? the algorithm seems to be fully explained

Comment: @brucesmitherson How exactly should I make the calculation of obtaining Va from a?

Comment: I guess 'variance' is jargon for velocity in acceleration measurements? If you have defined a 'window length' of $\Delta t$ and you have the local acceleration norm $a$, then the speed (not velocity) is $v=v0+a\Delta t$, right?

Comment: @brucesmitherson Va is average velocity, right? Right now I've a but don't know how to obtain Va from it. Should I use v=v0+aΔt? If so I don't know my v0.

Comment: @brucesmitherson My bad. Sorry. I receive the accelerometer data from the sensor every 1 second. The paper states to take the window length as 1 second as well. No variance right now. So therefore should I reduce the sensor interval, e.g. 0.2s, store all of the a values in 1 second and calculate the variance from there as normal distribution variance?

Comment: @brucesmitherson Anyways, thanks a lot for pointing me in the right direction. I'll take it from here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to determine the user status(static, slow walking, fast walking) by calculating the variance.

The Va in the research was not velocity. It was my mistake to interpret it as such. It was the variance of the euclidian norm of the accelerometer data.

I decreased the accelerometer update interval to 0.1s and every second I took 10 of the values and calculated their variance and compared that variance with the given thresholds.

The threshold required some tweaking since the research was conducted on a Nokia N95 where I'm on an iPhone 5.

Comment: @brucesmitherson You were right after all.

Comment: I am glad to have been of help!

Answer (score 0):

If you know the acceleration at each moment of time, *i*, then you can calculate the speed at the same moment *i* using the formula:

[image: Speed]

where T = 1 sec, for example, if the acceleration is sampled each second or if you have the average acceleration for each second.

Comment: If you check the comments under the question, we decided that Va is variance. It was my misunderstanding. Sorry. Do you not agree?

Comment: @CanSürmeli I apologize, I might be wrong, after reading the explanation again it does not make sense to me. That is why I erased my comments. For instance, T has units of acceleration variance, but then they talk about speed. No way to tell for me without reading the article in more detail.